# What can be the regular expression or regex for a file path or path?

Tags: c#, regex, expression, epplus

I am new to this. Please can anyone tell me what can be the regular expression for file path or any path :

Ex =>  `"C:\\\\Users\\\\1700000\\\\Downloads\\\\BackendApp\\\\WebApplication\\\\WebAPI_APPL\\\\Data\\\\1\\\\FirstFol\\\\SecondFodler\\\\MainFolder\\\\File.xlsx"`

or

`"C:\\\\Users\\\\1700000\\\\Downloads\\\\BackendApp\\\\WebApplication\\\\WebAPI_APPL\\\\Data\\\\1\\\\FirstFol\\\\SecondFodler\\\\MainFolder"`

File path or path can be **small or big**, it is not fixed. Path should start with **"C(any drive):\\"**
Please let me know what can I use also the expression should consider **double backslash** in it.

This expressions didn't work

1. `@"^(?:[\w]\:|\\\\)(\\\\[a-z_\-\s0-9\.]+)+\.(txt|gif|pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx)$"`
2. `@"^(?:[a-zA-Z]\:|\\\\\\\\[\w\.]+\\\\[\w.$]+)\\\\(?:[\w]+\\\\)*\w([\w.])+$"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
^(?:[\w]:|\\)([A-Za-z_\s0-9.-\\]+)\.(txt|gif|pdf|docx|doc|xlsx|xls)$
```

you could use https://regex101.com/ to try yours regex

Answer (score 0):

Here's one i've used in the past for unix based systems

```
(\/)((\w|-|_|[0-9])*\/(\w|-|_|[0-9])*)+[^.*\.]
```

For windows it will be essentially the same + detecting drive letter :

```
([A-Z]{1}:)(\/)((\w|-|_|[0-9])*\/(\w|-|_|[0-9])*)+[^.*\.]*
```

With backslashes :

```
([A-Z]{1}:)(\\\\)((\w|-|_|[0-9])*\\\\(\w|-|_|[0-9])*)+[^.*\.]*
```

When I used it I expected my strings to be paths only. It may capture text after a path so it's not perfect. But I hope this helps.